# Create PopUp with background behind it 50% transparent

Tags: java, android, popup, transparent

I created a `PopUp` using the following code:

**JAVA:**

```
public class PopUp extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * 0.6), (int) (height * 0.6));


}
```

**Style XML**

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Well, my `popUp` is good but i want a background half transparent behind it, not fully transparent as it is. I want something like this:

***Activity without popUp:***

[image: Activity without popUp]

***Activity with popUp:***

[image: Activity with popUp]

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) -- just use non-00 alpha channel values

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ColorDrawable dialogColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
    dialogColor.setAlpha(200);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dialogColor);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);


    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
```

and set alpha accordingly.